# Interactive ways to answer a yes or no question in a VR game?

Tags: game-design, virtual-reality

Currently, I am creating a VR game with a simple AI that at certain points ask for yes or no answers. Considering the player is free to walk around, I need a sort of spawn in and out kind of solution. I would really like this to be interactive and engaging. So far, I'm thinking to animate a "terminal" from the floor with a green and a red button on it and the user simple pushes down on one with their hand. I don't really want to use a 2D UI or a controller button press for this. Are there any other potential ways to handle this situation while keeping the interactivity there?

Comment: What kinds of input device(s) are you supporting?

Comment: It's going to be mainly supported on the Oculus Rift with Touch controllers or something similar to that.

Comment: "Go through door number one or door number 2", "take the blue pill or the red pill", "walk up the stairs or shoot yourself with this gun". Get creative! If it's a game, it should be fun.

Comment: Have you considered nodding / shaking your head?

Comment: Thumbs up and thumbs down works too if your controllers can track it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the terminal solution, you could just track controller position. The best part of VR is that you can translate motion and use the space as part of your design - even something as simple as a head nod/shake or pointing to a word could also work.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included a suggestion of *how* to map controller position to yes or no, *how* to detect a head nod/shake, or *how* to position a word and detect pointing at it.

Comment: @DMGregory - I was under the impression the game-design tag was for high level discussion and not technical details. Is that incorrect?

Comment: If you want upvotes, more detail is almost always helpful. :)